# Increment a var by one every 24 hours from a specific date

Tags: javascript, date, increment

I've never used Javascript before (or any other programming language) so sorry for asking this question because im sure it's very simple.

What I want to do is set a date in Javascript, then increment it by one every 24 hours. So three days after the date is set, 3 is displayed in the HTML (not the date itself). And after 100 days, 100 is displayed.

Thank you.

Comment: You should firstly understand that JavaScript running in browser sandbox and once user close the browser there will be no chance your JavaScript keep running, and once page reload the JavaScript variable will just be reset, so generally speaking in most cases you never get a chance see the number changed. You should find some other way to achieve your goal

Comment: JavaScript has to run somewhere (most commonly in a web browser)...it's usually bad to assume that a web browser will be open for any length of time (or at a specific time). It would be much better to use a job/service which is designed with this level of durability in mind.

Comment: You need to learn how to store data for long periods then look into the date object in javascript.

Comment: you can use setTimeout function for doing an action in fixed intervals

Comment: I don't suppose storing data is simple to do is it?

Comment: How would I go about using the Timeout function to achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create two date objects, one representing your initial date, and another one representing right now. Then, calculate the difference:

```
// Calculate days since Dec 1st 2012
var initialDate = new Date(2012, 11, 1); // Attention: month is zero-based
var now = Date.now();
var difference = now - initialDate;
var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);
alert(daysSince); // 80
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PmYFc/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show how many days the page has been open, you want to use the setInterval function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval.

So, if your HTML element looked like `<span id='example'>0</span>`, your JS might look like this:

```
var date = 0,
    element = document.getElementById("example");

setInterval(function(){
    date++;
    element.innerText = date;
}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); //milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours
```

Though, it seems unlikely any page would sit unrefreshed for any significant length of time. If you need to persist the date variable beyond page refreshes you could look into localstorage.